# MobieFirst v7.1 Application Center not sending push notifications to devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are implementing the GCM Push notification for app updates on AppCenter Client app

We have setup the following values in the server configuration

```
jndiName="ibm.appcenter.gcm.signature.googleapikey value="***"
jndiName="ibm.appcenter.push.schedule.period.unit" value="seconds"
jndiName="ibm.appcenter.push.schedule.period.amount" value="40"
```

And our app is still not receiving push notifications from GCM,
is there anything additional in the AppCenter Client to modify to enable this feature?

we have already set the **config.json** file **gcmProject** attribute with the GCM project number and rebuilt the apk accordingly.

the logs don't show any exceptions and no registered devices are available for push notification update

Answer (score 0):

This type of question does not fit StackOverflow, which is meant for programming-related questions. Please open an IBM PMR (support ticket) to address this kind of server configuration question.

Comment: As Per IBM's MobileFirst Help & Support info, all product questions can be placed on StackOverflow for community support...

Comment: Yes, I wrote that page. For this question you will need official support. StackOverflow is a community and does not guarantee you'll get an answer.